Operator spaces where the determinant determines the operator norm
We know that generally, the determinant doesn't determine the operator norm, but in some cases it does.
For example, let $\mathfrak E_3$ denote the real vector space of the traceless Hermitan $2\times 2$ complex matrices, that is, $\mathfrak E_3$ is the vector space that consists of the real linear combinations of the Pauli matrices.
Elements of $\mathfrak E_3$ can be viewed as linear operators acting on $\mathbb C^2$, and for any $A\in\mathfrak E_3$, $\|A\|^2 = -\mathrm{det}(A)$ where  $\|A\|$ is the operator norm of $A$.
From this follows that in $su(2):=i\mathfrak E_3$, $\|B\|^2 = \mathrm{det}(B)$ for any $B\in su(2)$.
$\mathfrak E_3$ and $su(2)$ are real subspaces of $\mathrm{lin}(\mathbb C^2,\mathbb C^2)$, in which the operator norm is a function of the determinant. Are there more examples of vector spaces
of linear operators where the operator norm is a function of the determinant?
